# How to join two tables on one similar column and any remainder on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have:
View_1

```
ID | col1 | col2 | col3
---+------+------+-----
1  | a200 | null | 5
2  | null | 300  | 6
```

View_2:

```
ID | colA | colB | colC
---+------+------+-----
1  | a200 | 400  | 40
2  | a500 | 300  | 60
```

What I want to do is join view 1 on to view 2 on View_1.col1=View_2.colA and do any leftover View_1 rows onto View 2 using a secondary column View_1.col2=View_2.colB...so I get something like this:

```
| a200 | 400 | 5 | 40
| a500 | 300 | 6 | 60
```

I thought doing two seperate inner joins and then union would do what I want...but I think I'm getting extra data.

What's the best way to do an initial join by one column, and then any rows that didnt match see if theres an inner join between them and View 2 but on a different column?

Comment: We don't have enough information here. What would happen in the event that both views have 6 rows, of which 4 don't match. Would you expect a Cartesian Product for these rows?

Comment: The "Leftover" View_1 are the rows with null value on col1 or these that dont match with any colA value from the View2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like

```
CREATE TABLE View_1
(
ID INT,
Col1 VARCHAR(20),
Col2 INT,
Col3 INT
);

CREATE TABLE View_2
(
ID INT,
ColA VARCHAR(20),
ColB INT,
ColC INT
);

INSERT INTO View_1 VALUES
(1, 'a200', null, 5),
(2, null, 300 , 6);

INSERT INTO View_2 VALUES
(1, 'a200', 400, 40),
(2, 'a500', 300, 60);

SELECT COALESCE(V1.Col1, V2.ColA) Column1,
       COALESCE(V1.Col2, V2.ColB) Column2,
       V1.Col3 Column3,
       V2.ColC Column4
FROM View_1 V1 INNER JOIN View_2 V2
     ON V1.Col1 = V2.ColA OR V1.Col2 = V2.ColB;
```

Results:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | a200    |     400 |       5 |      40 |
|  2 | a500    |     300 |       6 |      60 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**[Demo](https://rextester.com/DII24703)**

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an `OR` condition with your `INNER JOIN` and then use `CASE Statements` to return non-nulls, this solution returns your example of what you want returned:

```
DECLARE @temp1 TABLE ([Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1), [col1] varchar(10), [col2] INT, [col3] INT)
DECLARE @temp2 TABLE([Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1), [col1] varchar(10), [colB] INT, [colC] INT)

INSERT INTO @temp1
([col1], [col2], [col3])
VALUES('a200', NULL, 5), (NULL, 300, 6)

INSERT INTO @temp2
([col1], [colB], [colC])
VALUES('a200', 400, 40), ('a500', 300, 60)

SELECT CASE WHEN t1.[col1] IS NULL THEN t2.[col1] ELSE t1.[col1] END AS [col1], CASE WHEN t1.[col2] IS NULL THEN t2.[colB] ELSE t1.[col2] END AS [col2], t1.[col3], t2.[colC]
FROM @temp1 AS t1
INNER JOIN @temp2 AS t2
ON t2.[col1] = t1.[col1] OR t2.[colB] = t1.[col2]
```